# Need to write the groovy script for generating pom.xml file using ant build artifacts in jfrog artifactory

Tags: maven, groovy, ant, artifactory

Developer wrote the code in build.xml so i wrote the groovy script for ant build and generated the artifacts in jfrog artifactory.

Now they need pom.xml file from jfrog artifactory. Now I need to write the groovy script in jenkins job to automate the process for generating the pom file from ant build artifacts.

Comment: Why generating a pom file from ant build...it would be much more easier to migrate to Maven...And what is exactly the question?

Comment: Ivy or Maven ant tasks can do this.